# Circular border around another image is not drawing in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

I have a **picture box control** which I have made circular and now I am trying to draw a red circle around it using this:

```
 Graphics gf = pictureBoxLastLogin1.CreateGraphics();
 gf.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBoxLastLogin1.Width+12, pictureBoxLastLogin1.Height+12));
```

But it is not drawing anything around the image? What i am doing wrong? Remember i have converted square image to circular image using this code snippet.

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, pictureBoxLastLogin.Width , pictureBoxLastLogin.Height);
Region rg = new Region(gp);
pictureBoxLastLogin.Region = rg;
```

Comment: For persistent drawing use the Paint event and it s e.Graphics obejtct. For non-perstent drawing do not Invalidate the control!

Comment: paint event only fires once, what should i do if i want to change the border colour?

Comment: If you use the Paint event you should change the color it uses and then do an Invalidate on the control.

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics() to draw, the pixels you splatter have a limited lifetime.  When you paint *outside* of the picturebox then it must be the parent's Paint event that does the job.  Ensure that the pb's LocationChanged and SizeChanged events force an Invalidate() call on the parent.  The parent also needs its ResizeRedraw property set to true.  Clearly this will be a lot easier to get going when you let the PB draw that border, *inside* the PB.

Comment: In addition, the Region does not allow anti-aliasing and that tends to be pretty noticeable on a low-resolution display.  It will look a lot better when you draw everything yourself, using a circular clip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we draw on a Control and we want the drawing to persist, we need to subscribe to the [Paint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Paint);k(System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) event of that Control. Or, if it's a Custom Control (a custom class derived from an existing object), to override it's [OnPaint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_OnPaint_System_Windows_Forms_PaintEventArgs_) method.

A Control DC is redrawn quite often. When another Window moves over it, when its `Form` container is Minimized/Maximized or resized, if this touches a Control visible area an so on.

When a redrawing is required, the `Paint()` event is raised.
A drawing will be preserved only if it is coded inside the `Paint()` event handler (or the `OnPaint()` method).
It's also importat to notice that most of the object used implement [`IDisposable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.2).
They all need to be [`Disposed()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2). Here, the `GraphicsPath` object and the drawing `Pen`.
The `Region` applied to the `PicturBox` should also be disposed. It could be declared at class scope and disposed when the `Form` closes.

An example, using (more or less) the same settings used in the question.

---

A `Form` containing a `PictureBox` and 2 `Buttons`:
When `Button1` is clicked, it will create a elliptic `Region` for the `PictureBox`.
`Button2` will [`Invalidate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invalidate);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) the `PictureBox`, causing a re-paint to be to *scheduled*. The `Paint()` event will be raised.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

bool PaintBorder = false;
int RegionInSet = 8;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        path.AddEllipse(RegionInSet, RegionInSet, pictureBox1.Width - (RegionInSet * 2), 
                        pictureBox1.Height - (RegionInSet * 2));
        Region region = new Region(path);
        pictureBox1.Region = region;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PaintBorder = true;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!PaintBorder) return;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;

    using (Pen penRed = new Pen(Color.Red, 12))
    {
        int PenRedOffset = (int)(penRed.Width / 2) + (penRed.Width % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 0);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(penRed,
            new RectangleF(RegionInSet + PenRedOffset, RegionInSet + PenRedOffset,
                           pictureBox1.Width - (PenRedOffset * 2) - (RegionInSet * 2),
                           pictureBox1.Height - (PenRedOffset * 2) - (RegionInSet * 2)));
    }
}
```

Visual result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i can change your paint event logic to this simple line.    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red, 10), 0, 0, pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);

Comment: @Muhammad Faizan Khan  No, you can't :) (<= See the smiley?) That code 1) Takes care of the Region size (as it is, the single line you posted doesn't draw anything; it's drawing outside the Region 2) `new Pen(Color.Red, 10)` a `Pen` is a Graphics object. It needs to be disposed, either implicitly (calling `.Dispose()`) or implicitly (wrapping it in a `using` statement ). The way you want to use it, you're leaking GDI resources each time `Paint()` is raised (many, many times). 3) `Graphics.DrawEllipse()` draws the border half inside and half outside the rectangle bounds. You'ld lose half of it.

Comment: @Muhammad Faizan Khan  4) Assume you need a thinner frame. How would you do it, if you plan to ditch the Region? And what if the Bitmap grows in size? Or the screen DPI changes? How the simple DrawEllipse will fit these changes. Well, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you invalidate it, windows is going to redraw it which in-turn is going to remove whatever drawing that you have done on it.

Use `Paint` event, whatever you are going to draw in paint event will remain there.